# What aspect of AWS S3 Glacier costs does the Max Retrieval Policy Cap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I have a single 15GB file stored in Glacier (EU-Ireland) that I want to retrieve.

I can't retrieve it using the free tier because it is larger than 10GB.

I am looking at the Max Retrieval Rate vs No Retrieval Limit Policies.

If I set Max Retrieval Rate to 15GB/hr, the console says my retrieval cost is $108/month or less.

If I choose that, and retrieve my file, and perform no other Glacier activities this month how much will I pay? Conversely, if I set No Retrieval Limit, and retrieve my file, how much will I pay?

Those are my questions, here are my presumed answers... can you validate?

- Storage: I'll pay 15GB * 0.004 = $0.06
- Standard Retrieval: 15GB * $0.1 = $0.15
- Data Transfer Out: 1GB * $0.00 + 14GB * $0.09 = $1.26
- Total for the month: $1.47

The pricing page doesn't mention how retrieval rate plays into the pricing. Any clarification and/or advice? If I set Max Retrieval Rate to 15GB/hr, which aspect of the cost is limited to $108/mo?

Comment: I suspect that the concept of a "retrieval rate" is no longer current. Instead, Glacier offers **Retrieval Pricing** as Expedited/Standard/Bulk. Can you point us to some documentation (preferably from AWS) that refers to the "retrieval rate"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein You can read about the details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/data-retrieval-policy.html

Comment: Mmm, interesting! This differs from the explanations on [Retrieving Glacier Archives - Amazon S3 Glacier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/downloading-an-archive-two-steps.html). I suspect that pricing is based on expedited/standard/bulk, but the retrieval rate is an additional throttling mechanism to cap costs. Somewhat confusing.